# How to fill in data frame column values by matching another data frame?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame with x and y coordinates like this:

```
          x        y
1  3.984804 4.470310
2  3.985005 4.470310
3  3.985071 4.470310
4  3.985262 4.469213
5  3.985262 4.469213
6  3.985262 4.469213
7  3.985001 4.471442
8  3.985001 4.471759
9  3.984981 4.472782
10 3.985001 4.478800
```

dput output:

```
structure(list(x = c(3.98480399, 3.98500453380952, 3.98507138190476,
3.98526204428571, 3.98526204428571, 3.98526204428571, 3.98500133714286,
3.98500133714286, 3.98498099190476, 3.98500133714286), y = c(4.47030988428572,
4.47030988428572, 4.47030988428572, 4.46921270476191, 4.46921270476191,
4.46921270476191, 4.47144165047619, 4.47175932380952, 4.47278151761905,
4.47880045571429)), numFrames = 68418L, fps = 50, units = "mm", timeUnits = "s", row.names = c(NA,
10L), class = c("Trajectory", "data.frame"))
```

And I have another data frame with coordinates like this:

```
          x1       y1
1  0.1466667 3.053333
2  0.1466667 3.446667
3  0.1466667 3.753333
4  0.1933333 4.053333
5  0.2800000 4.400000
6  0.4066667 4.653333
7  0.5400000 4.920000
8  0.7133333 5.193333
9  0.8400000 5.366667
10 8.2133333 5.233333
11 8.3733333 5.066667
12 8.5133333 4.853333
13 8.6866667 4.613333
14 8.7933333 4.440000
15 8.9066667 4.180000
16 9.0066667 3.526667
17 9.1200000 3.513333
18 9.1533333 3.046667
19 9.1400000 2.880000
```

dput output:

```
structure(list(x1 = c(0.146666666666667, 0.146666666666667, 0.146666666666667,
0.193333333333333, 0.28, 0.406666666666667, 0.54, 0.713333333333333,
0.84, 8.21333333333333, 8.37333333333333, 8.51333333333333, 8.68666666666667,
8.79333333333333, 8.90666666666667, 9.00666666666667, 9.12, 9.15333333333333,
9.14), y1 = c(3.05333333333333, 3.44666666666667, 3.75333333333333,
4.05333333333333, 4.4, 4.65333333333333, 4.92, 5.19333333333333,
5.36666666666667, 5.23333333333333, 5.06666666666667, 4.85333333333333,
4.61333333333333, 4.44, 4.18, 3.52666666666667, 3.51333333333333,
3.04666666666667, 2.88)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-19L))
```

and I want add a column to the first data frame where the new column is the y1 value from the second data frame with the closest x value between the data frames.

For example the first row would be:

```
          x        y        y1
1  3.984804 4.470310 4.4653333
```

because row 6 in the second data frame's x1 is closest to the x in the first data frame, so that y value is added.

Comment: I think `9  0.8400000 5.366667` in 2nd data set is the closest match to 3.984804, not the one you have chosen, `6  0.4066667 4.653333`. Or should some of the x values in 2nd data be 10x higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
d1 <- structure(list(x = c(3.98480399, 3.98500453380952, 3.98507138190476,
3.98526204428571, 3.98526204428571, 3.98526204428571, 3.98500133714286,
3.98500133714286, 3.98498099190476, 3.98500133714286), y = c(4.47030988428572,
4.47030988428572, 4.47030988428572, 4.46921270476191, 4.46921270476191,
4.46921270476191, 4.47144165047619, 4.47175932380952, 4.47278151761905,
4.47880045571429)), numFrames = 68418L, fps = 50, units = "mm", timeUnits = "s", row.names = c(NA,
10L), class = c("Trajectory", "data.frame"))

d2 <- structure(list(x1 = c(0.146666666666667, 0.146666666666667, 0.146666666666667,
0.193333333333333, 0.28, 0.406666666666667, 0.54, 0.713333333333333,
0.84, 8.21333333333333, 8.37333333333333, 8.51333333333333, 8.68666666666667,
8.79333333333333, 8.90666666666667, 9.00666666666667, 9.12, 9.15333333333333,
9.14), y1 = c(3.05333333333333, 3.44666666666667, 3.75333333333333,
4.05333333333333, 4.4, 4.65333333333333, 4.92, 5.19333333333333,
5.36666666666667, 5.23333333333333, 5.06666666666667, 4.85333333333333,
4.61333333333333, 4.44, 4.18, 3.52666666666667, 3.51333333333333,
3.04666666666667, 2.88)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                              -19L))



## calculate diff from all of x to all of x1:
dm <- abs(outer( d1$x, d2$x1, FUN="-" ))

## find closest per row:
i.closest <- apply( dm, 1, which.min )

d1$y1 <- d2$y1[i.closest]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `max.col`+ `outer` like below

```
d1$y1 <- d2$y1[max.col(-abs(outer(d1$x, d2$x1, "-")))]
```